# Is this statement concerning limit by using neighborhood true?

Tags: analysis

I am wondering if this statement below is true?

> Let $f\colon D\subset \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},$ and $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ be a limit point of $D,$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}.$ Then $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=A,$ if and only if for every neighborhood $\mathbb{B}(A,\epsilon)$ of $A,$ its preimage $f^{-1}(\mathbb{B}(A,\epsilon))$ is a deleted neighborhood of $x_0.$

Here $\mathbb{B}(A,\epsilon)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}\mid |y-A|<\epsilon\}.$ And we call $U$ is a deleted neighborhood of $x_0,$ if there exists an open set $O$ such that $(O\backslash\{x_0\})\subset U.$

Comment: Yes, this statement is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have not seen this in standard Analysis textbooks. Since I think this statement is easy to visualizer the definition of limit of function, I'll be very appreciated, if you recommend some references.